# Using different page layout for login page

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to implement a SPA with AngularJS. I have a main page layout where the left side deals with navigation links and the top right corner contains username and user preference options as well and of course most of the page deals with the content of each navigation path.

What I'm trying to do is if the user is not logged in, redirect him to a login page that has a completely different layout (the login form centered and that's all).

How can this be done in a simple manner?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am also in the process of implementing this feature. I will be treating login and the authenticated application as two different SPAs. So there will be 2 different server routes one for the login and one for the application.

This will allow me to not have my ng-view on the body tag so I don't need to have my header and sidebar logic replicated on every route.

Comment: The login page can be a simple page, and may not require you to setup any angular code as it would have very limited functionality.

Comment: Excellent point, I will be doing that to allow for other features such as forgot password and account creation. Those could also be separate pages too, but by using angular it will be a consistent dev environment for my team.

Comment: Lot of the server framework such as ASP.Net MVC provide boilerplate code for authenitcation which one can use just out of the box. It comes with all, register, login, forgot password, change password.

Comment: Precisely, I am using the ASP.Net Identity auth mechanism ask those features are part of the account controller. I am just writing the part that consumes those exposed endpoints.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ng-view` on the body tag so you can change the whole layout

```
<body ng-view>
</body>
```

Comment: I know that, they question is what is the easiest way to deal with the 2 different layout if I want to embed more templates as well in them, maybe for more then just 1 layer.
Also, where and how should I configure the routeProvider? There has to be an abvious /login part that renders the 1st type of body but how should I deal with for example /products/categories/super_category/
?