# AngularJS - Create a login page with a totally different layout

Tags: angularjs, rest, layout, authentication, token

I am new to AngularJS and I need to implement a totally different layout for the login page.

I have read many articles, all of them have theoretical answers but I have some implementation questions as well.

I am going to do two SPAs, one for the application, and one for the login (need another background, no header, no left bar, etc.) as https://stackoverflow.com/a/23154848/6009677

My backend login way is making a POST request to a "/rest/v1/login" endpoint and it returns a token which I have to send all over the requests in the header.

How can I achieve to have one SPA for the login, and once the server returns the token, go to the content SPA logged in with the token.

Maybe there is another solution with only one ng app?

Thank you.